# SwiftUI NavigationStack NavigationLink same Value, multiple destinations

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a model like so...

```
struct User: Codable {
    let followersCount: Int
    let followingCount: Int
}
```

Using NavigationStack I would like to be able to use NavigationLink based on Value

```
 NavigationLink(value: user.followersCount) {
    Text("Followers")
}

NavigationLink(value: user.followingCount) {
    Text("Following")
}
.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
    FollowersView()
}

.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
    FollowingView()
}
```

As both values are an Int. Is there a way to differentiate the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare an object:

```
enum Link {
   case followers(Int)
   case following(Int)
}
```

then use it like:

```
NavigationLink(value: Link.followers(user.followersCount)) {
    Text("Followers")
}

NavigationLink(value: Link.following(user.followingCount)) {
    Text("Following")
}

.navigationDestination(for: Link) { link in
    switch link {
    case let .followers(count):
        FollowersView()
    case let .following(count):
        FollowingView()
    }
}
```